# Migrate from Oracle 9.2 to 11g

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-9i

I have a executable application that using Oracle ODBC Driver V9.2. My Old server Have Oracle 10g on windows 2003 32bit. I install and configure new server using Oracle 11g on Windows Server 2016 x64.
SQL*Plus on My client PC can connect to My Oracle 11g On server side, but my application failed to connect to server.
I Installed Oracle 11g ODBC Driver on client, But my problem still exists.

Comment: In the absence of any error messages or trace data to give detail, It's impossible to say what is going on without knowing more about your application and how it was designed to work.

Comment: When I try to connect my old Client with desktop application that contain ODBC 9.2 to new server (Windows server 2016, Oracle 11g), I get 

    ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed

Comment: When I install Windows 2016 with Oracle Client 11g, and try to open my application, I get "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

Comment: Sounds like the application isn't compatible with the newer drivers or - by extension - the newer (though still ancient) version of Oracle database. I'd suggest finding or building a new application. Use a version of Oracle that's actually current (even 11g has mostly been unsupported for many, many years already).

Comment: I don't access to source code. but today I try to run my desktop application on my Windows 2003 server. my application can show "Oracle ODBC Driver Connection (Version 10.2.0.1.0)" window. but I get "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor ,Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed" and "TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused"

Comment: So then it sounds like your tnsnames.ora in the Oracle Client is mis-configured, and pointing to an invalid service.

Comment: Yes. You are right. thanks. my app started well on server

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Feel free to answer your own question  if pmdba doesn't have time to make his comment an answer; that way folks won't need to read your question and the comments to find out you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, But you must attrition to Configure new server as same as current server and use same architecture ODBC driver. In this case I had two mistake, first, I used X64 version of ODBC instead of x86 and second one was I used wrong service name in  "tnsnames.ora" file.